# How can you tell if a Swift class is inheriting from another class or is conforming to a protocol?

Tags: xcode, swift

For example, if we have a class `Foo` that inherits from class `Bar`, and conforms to the protocol `Baz`:

```
class Bar {}

protocol Baz {}
```

`class Foo: Bar, Baz {}`

What if we don't know ahead of time that `Bar` is a class and `Baz` is a protocol (For example, when reading someone else's code).
In this case, it *might be* clear due to there being multiple declarations after `class Foo:`. In Swift, the protocol conformance declaration must come after the superclass declaration in the inheritance clause. On the other hand, this could also be a class with no inheritance that conforms to multiple protocols.

Also what if there is only one declaration in the inheritance clause?

```
class Foo: Bar {}
```

Or:

```
class Foo: Baz {}
```

In Objective-C, it is clear since the protocol name is surrounded by angle brackets. In Swift, angle brackets are used for generics. Is there syntax support for making protocol conformance more visually explicit for this scenario?

Comment: Won't the difference become obvious once `Baz` starts warning you that you have unimplemented required methods, which `Bar` won't do?  I mean, in usage of the class, there's little difference, right?  You're going to try it as an object of a particular type, and that particular type might be a protocol.

Comment: For example, in Objective-C, the difference between `for (id<NSObject> obj in myArray)` and `for(NSObject *obj in myArray)` is completely non-existent.  The syntax in this single line looks different, but usage within the loop is identical.  Why does it matter whether it's a protocol or a class?  (You can also rightclick-gotodefintion)

Comment: what about the naming conventions? the protocol can be `BazProtocol` or `BazDelegate` – depending in what the protocol purpose is – and that can identify it quickly if you read the _header_ or the _extension_ of the class.

Comment: @holex I assume Bryan is probably talking about a situation where you haven't written the code yourself and some idiot is ignoring naming conventions.  If you wrote the code yourself, you'd probably know what they are no matter what they're named.

Comment: Also, just to add to this, a class can conform to more than one protocol, so `class Foo: Bar, Baz {}` doesn't guarantee `Bar` to be a superclass, just guarantees `Baz` to be a protocol.

Comment: @nhgrif, I understood that, I'm just not seeing why the naming convention is a problem here. the names serve the developer, e.g. the developer could use class names like `C0001`, `C0002`, etc... but after a point the developer will lost the point which class serves which purpose. no one else can help on the developer then, even if the _ObjC_ is used because the `@interface C0062 : C0047 <P0123, P0072> { }` would mean nothing, even if the developer can identify the `P0123` and `P0072` are kinds of protocols or what.

Comment: You're right.  But the main point here is that I don't think Bryan is talking about a class that he wrote that is a subclass/conforms to protocol that he wrote.  He's talking about looking at a project that someone else wrote (or at least a subset of a project) and he wants to easily be able to identify whether this is a subclass or it is just conforming to a protocol.  There's no way for him to go back in time and fix the poor naming conventions that don't indicate class/protocol left by a previous developer or his former self.

Comment: That is a good point about multiple protocols with no inheritance, which is another scenario to think about when reading code.

Comment: @holex Naming conventions would definitely help with readability, but the code may not be named well :(

Answer (score 4):

Swift handles Protocols mostly in the same way it handles types. This is by design and one of the consequences is the difficulty to immediately differentiate between protocol conformance and class inheritance in many instances.

Whether this is a positive or negative thing is a matter of opinion and is up for discussion. As such, I will not address it.

#### More to the practical aspects:

The quickest way to identify whether a given keyword refers to a `Protocol` or a `Class` is to **option-click** the keyword. Here are the results of doing so in each case:

[image: class]
[image: protocol]

Of course, this only makes sense if you're reading the code on Xcode.